# How to efficiently visit multiple paths of a nested dictionary with nested lists

Tags: python, path, tree, backtracking

Say I have a nested dictionary like so:

```
{
    'a': {
        'z': [
            {
                'x': 1,
                'y': [
                    [{'a': 10}, {'f': 21}],
                    {'m': 100},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    'm': {
        'x': 100
    }
}
```

And let's say I have a list of paths that have no relative order to each other:

```
[('a', 'z', 'x'), ('m', 'x'), ('a', 'z', 'y', 'a'), ...]
```

And I want to update whatever value the final key is for all these paths to some value `val`. Notice that in the third tuple, the last key is `a`, but it sits in a list.

In my data, these assumptions can be made:

- key names can be repeated in a single path (notice `'a'` is the source and destination node in the third tuple)
- destination "nodes" are always a string, int, float, boolean, i.e. - never ending on a list or another dictionary
- lists only hold other lists or dictionaries

My thoughts:

1. My current implementation is a brute force approach which is too slow for my requirements: iterate from source to destination for every single one of these paths, detecting if I am on a list or dictionary.
2. Ideally, I would back track and visit nearby nodes that need to be visited as well, so that I don't have to start from the top level again. This kind of reminds me of visiting multiple stops/cities on a trip.
3. I was also thinking of a trie, but I think that would still mean starting from source to destination. Also I don't think a trie would work since we have lists.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It will be inefficient to have to scan lists in order to find a certain key/value. Moreover, there might be multiple list elements that match. Is it not possible to include in your paths the *index* of the intended list element? The third example would then have to be `('a', 'z', 'y', 0, 'a')`. That would make a solution efficient and unambiguous.

Comment: Should a solution like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73144408/5387738 suit you, let me know. We could try to build something similar.

Comment: @trincot that would be ideal, but it's not the case. Fortunately the lists are capped, so it's constant in that sense. The trickier part IMO is having to re-traverse the common paths / prefixes that may have already been traversed in another path.

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews Hi, have you tried my solution? The caching should help with not revisiting paths; I'm just curious if it performs any better. Thanks!

Comment: @thariqfahry I did take a look at it and I like the idea. Was waiting to see if anyone else would post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache previously-visited nodes in a dictionary and store their references.

```
# Helper function to flatten nested lists.
def flatten(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x


# The cache stores all already-visited paths.
cache = {}


def setValue(nested_dict, path, value):
    queue = nested_dict
    depth = 0

    # Find the largest subpath that's already in the cache (=already visited),
    # starting with the full path and removing one key at a time from the end.
    for end_index in range(len(path), 0, -1):
        if path[0:end_index] in cache:
            queue = cache[path[0:end_index]]
            depth = len(path[0:end_index])
            break

    # For the rest of the keys in the path (unvisited), visit them and
    # store their references in the cache.
    while depth < len(path) - 1:
        if type(queue) is dict:
            queue = queue[path[depth]]
        elif type(queue) is list:
            queue = [i for i in flatten(queue) if path[depth] in i][0][path[depth]]
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Unknown data type at {path}[{depth}]")

        cache[path[0 : depth + 1]] = queue
        depth += 1

    # For the final key, change its dictionary value to 'value'.
    if type(queue) is dict:
        queue[path[depth]] = value
    elif type(queue) is list:
        [i for i in flatten(queue) if path[depth] in i][0][path[depth]] = value
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"Unknown data type at {path}[{depth}]")


data = {
    'a': {
        'z': [
            {
                'x': 1,
                'y': [
                    [{'a': 10}, {'f': 21}],
                    {'m': 100},
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    'm': {
        'x': 100
    }
}

setValue(data, ("a", "z", "x"), 900)
setValue(data, ("a", "z", "y", "a"), 901)
setValue(data, ("a", "z", "y", "f"), 902)
setValue(data, ("a", "z", "y", "m"), 903)
setValue(data, ("m", "x"), 904)

print(data)
```

The nested lists make traversal slightly tricky, but they can just be [flattened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/14449940). Looking up an item by value in a list will obviously be slower than looking up a key in a dictionary because you lose the hash table, but that's mitigated in this case by only having to do it once per node.